# my image are not saved in upload folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

whenever I uploaded an image in laravel, the image is upload to the database but after database uploading, my image didn't save that image in my root folder,

here is my upload code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $records = $request->all();

    if ($records != '') {
        if ($request->session()->has('is_user_logged')) {
            $UserPostModel = new UserPostModel;
            $UserPostModel->uid = $request->session()->get('uid');
            $UserPostModel->uname = $request->session()->get('name');
            $UserPostModel->msg = $request->input('status');
            $UserPostModel->eid = $request->input('event');
            
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {

                    $fileName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
                    $fileName = time() . "_" . $fileName;
                              
                    $request->file = move_uploaded_file('uploads',$fileName);
           

                    $UserPostModel->image = $fileName;
                }
            }
            $UserPostModel->save();

            return redirect('uprofile')->with('message', 'Seccessfully Post !');
        } else {
            return redirect('login');
        }
    } else {

        return redirect('/uprofile')->with('message', 'Please select image!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `store` method and pass the driver as the second argument

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store($store_path, 'public');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code with your image upload condition.

```
 if ($file = $request->file('image')) {

        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('uploads', $name);
        $UserPostModel->image = $name;
}
     $UserPostModel -> save();
```